# python logging 'disabled' set to True

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I use the logging package:

```
configuration_logger = logging.getLogger("configuration")
```

It writes a few logs, then for the next one I see that `configuration_logger.disabled` is True.
How can I check why it was changed to True?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably because you called [`logging.config.fileConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig) or [`logging.config.dictConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig) without declaring `disable_existing_loggers` to be `False` (see [this search result](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html?highlight=disable_existing_loggers)). The default value of this is `True` only for reasons of backward compatibility.

You should generally configure logging (using e.g. the above functions) before logging anything.